# how to change the color of the number of figures in latex

Tags: floats, color, packages

how can I change the color of the number of figures in the text? what I have is red as you can see in the attached photo. How can I change it to blue or black?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{iopart}

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor = blue, urlcolor = blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\expandafter\let\csname equation*\endcsname=\relax % to fix some errors regarding asmath because it is not friendly with iopart publisher
\expandafter\let\csname endequation*\endcsname=\relax
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[RPvoltages]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\hbadness=6000
\overfullrule=1pt
\hfuzz=2pt
\pdfoutput=1
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the argument of `\usepackage{hyperref}`, add `linkcolor = blue`, or balck, or any other color you would like. The new command will read `\usepackage[colorlinks, citecolor = blue, urlcolor = blue, linkcolor = blue]{hyperref}`

Link color refers to any internal links in the document, such as references to figures as you have, or references to sections, tables, ect.

Comment: Added a comment because it specific to your case- so far all the hyperlink colors you've specified are blue. Maybe you would be interested in using `allcolors = blue` as an argument to hyperref

Comment: thank you so much